# "Unable to run arch-specific checks"

Tags: archlinux, shared-libraries

I'm using a Raspberry Pi to run pywws, in support of a personal weather station.  I noticed that it had stopped working, so rebooted my Pi; however, now I'm getting peculiar errors with simple Linux commands.

Here's an example:-

```
jeremy@raspberrypi ~ $ ps -ef | grep pywws
ps: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libprocps.so.
0: Unable to run arch-specific checks
```

I've had an unsuccessful Google for this error but with no luck and now I'm stumped.

I've checked the library exists.

```
jeremy@raspberrypi ~ $ ls -l /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libprocps.so.0*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    18 Mar 29  2013 /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libprocps.so.
0 -> libprocps.so.0.0.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 59308 Mar 29  2013 /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libprocps.so.
0.0.1
```

Suggestions gratefully received.  I hadn't logged onto the Pi for a couple of weeks, so nothing has been consciously changed.

Comment: Hello and welcome! What's the version of the OS?

Comment: `Linux raspberrypi 3.12.28+ #709 PREEMPT Mon Sep 8 15:28:00 BST 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux`

Comment: I think it might be a fault with the SD card.  I tried to install `htop` in order to get some more diagnostics and in the middle of the apt-get output was `segmentation fault`.  If I try to start pywws manually, I get an `IOError: open failed`.  As a result, I'm going to `fsck` the SD card using another machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did an `fsck.ext4`, which seemed to find some problems with the SD card.  Just to be on the safe side, I rebuilt it.  I guess the SD card is on its way out.

The `IOError` with pywws is a separate issue.